# IIS My Web Sites Folder Deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am using .Net and IIS. I accidentally deleted the My Web Sites folder (see path below) used by IIS on accident, and am unable to recover these files. As a result, I am no longer able to run my project in Visual Studio on my localmachine. Should I reinstall IIS, or does anybody have any ideas as to what I should do. Thanks.

*User* \ Documents \ My Web Sites \ *Project* \ web.config

Comment: Is the folder in the Recycle Bin? *Are you using source code control?*

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not in the Recycle Bin; I wish it were that easy. For this particular project, my company has a repository through Github that I use. However, this folder for IIS was on my localmachine only, and not accessible through source control.

Comment: In that case, you're pretty much out of luck. A forensic data expert could retrieve it, but that's costly. Let this be a lesson to always keep backups of your computer and have your code in source code control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating an empty IIS My Websites folder and then booting up Visual Studio. Visual Studio saw that the folder was there and I was able to start using my projects again.

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same problem after deleting the "my web sites" folder. The error message that Visual Studio showed was that it tries to read web.config from a specific location. I just created the file again with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration></configuration>
```

That solved my problem. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I just needed to create the directory tree Documents\My Web Sites\myweb-Site

Answer (score 1):

If You've permanently deleted the folder You can use recovery tool to recover your data. Like you can use [this tool](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) (Recuva) to recover those files and set up Your visual studio again for Your project.